# How to Validate Password and Confirm Password using Javascript without using Regular Expression?

Tags: javascript, validation, passwords

I want to validate "password" and "confirm password" of Form by using javascript. But the challenge is that we have to use "regular expression" for validation. we have to write pure javascript code for validation. How to solve this problem ??

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? Here we expect you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please attempt something, then update your question to show a **specific** problem you're having in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: You would use the regular expression to validate that the password contains certain characters or is a particular length. Then you would simply compare the two passwords to check if the 'Confirm Password' is therefore also valid.

Comment: Are you even talking client or server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regular expression can ensure the passwords are of a particular pattern. For example, they may need to be between certain lengths and contain various special characters. You can then validate the confirmed password by comparing both password entries.

```js
function didClickValidate() {
  console.log(validate())
}

function validate() {
  const patt = document.getElementById('patt').value
  const pass = document.getElementById('pass').value
  const conf = document.getElementById('conf').value
  
  return new RegExp(patt).test(pass) && pass === conf  
}
```

```html
<input id="patt" type="string" placeholder="Pattern" value="(?=.*[0-9])"/><hr>
<input id="pass" type="password" placeholder="Password" /><br>
<input id="conf" type="password" placeholder="Confirmation"/>

<button onclick="didClickValidate()">Validate</button>
```